# Unable to find a specification for `Alamofire (~> 3.5)`

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire

```
target 'MyApp' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for MyApp
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.5'  end
  target 'MyAppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'MyAppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing


end
```

This is the pod file, swift 2.3, Xcode VERSION 7.3.1. I'm trying to install alamofire ,  but I'm getting the error above, i searched google , but there wasn't any useful things to do. any help?

Comment: Maybe because Alamofire went from "3.4.1" to "4.0.0"?

Comment: tried it but also didn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'MyProject' do
use_frameworks!

# Pods for MyProject
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'
end
```

Hopefully this must work. Check for your Pod version also.

Answer (score 2):

First of all try make higher deployment target
if not work then
Try to run these command one by one

- pod repo remove master
- pod setup
- pod update